# Free Tool for diagramming

Tags: macos, applications, design

I am looking for a **free tool for drawing diagrams** (either for OS X or online). My goal is to keep for myself a clear trace of the organization of my project. Something like [OmniGraffle](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle).

Any ideas?

Actually, I want to design a [class diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram).

Answer (score 2):

[yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/) is free and is available for OS X, Windows and Linux.